# Copying data from one column to another in the same table - Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table in this format:

```
a   |   b
----------
12.1| NULL
6.4 | NULL
55.5| NULL
```

I want to simply copy the values from a over to b.

I've reviewed other answers to this question, and it appears people are able to do this with a simple query:

```
UPDATE table
SET b = a
```

However, this is producing the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Is there something I need to review in my database that's making this not work?  Is there an alternative query I can or should be using?

Comment: There is no subquery in that code. There's something important for this question you're not telling us.

Comment: Joel, you were right but I promise I didn't leave anything out intentionally.  Zohar pointed out below there was likely a trigger on that table, which when disabled allowed me to run it correctly.

Comment: If that error appears in a trigger I would be willing to bet that your trigger has some major flaws. It probably assumes there is only a single row in inserted and/or deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bet your table have a trigger for update, and that trigger is what's causing this issue.
The fact is that triggers in sql server are raised per statement, not per row. 
This means that for the sample data you provided, the update statement will produce an inserted table with 3 records. 
I'll bet in your trigger you do something like this:

```
select @localVariable = a from inserted.
```

This is what's causing the problem.

Comment: You were right!  I found a trigger affected that table and disabled it, which fixed the problem.  Thank you so much!

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)