# Simple insert into give the "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I keep getting this error and I cannot see how it is possible with the following statement.

```
INSERT INTO table_name
       ([RecordID]
       ,[IMA_RecordID]
       ,[Code]
       ,[InActiveFlag]
       ,[DefaultFlag])
 VALUES
       (NEWID(),'value 1','value 2',0,1),
   (NEWID(),'value 3','value 4',0,1);
```

Can someone help me see what is causing the issue?

Comment: My guess, you have a trigger on `table_name` that **assumes** that an `INSERT` contains one row.

Comment: Thank you Larnu.  This is exactly the issue but I don't have a way to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Launenhaft this is probably a duplicate question anyway...

Comment: it isn't really an answer on it's own, @Launenhaft; just an educated guess. An answer would be converting the poorly written trigger to a set based trigger, which we can't do as we don't have the definition.

Comment: When I searched, there were plenty that had this error but not this circumstance.

Comment: I never thought to check for triggers (this is an inherited database).  This is the only answer I needed to move forward with inserting values.  I completely agree the trigger that exists is garbage (much like most of what the previous developer did).

Comment: [Here's one for update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44290006/3094533) and [one for insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39464782/3094533) - and that's just a taste. There are plenty more where [these came from.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+insert+subquery+returned+more+than+1+value)